# toastr package Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, package, installation, toastr

I'm trying to use `Toastr` package in my application to have alerts displayed to the user. I followed the  tutorial [here](https://github.com/yoeunes/toastr) but now I can't have access to my app; I'm having this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:234 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(397): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(374): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(289): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(188): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExcepti in C:\xampp\htdocs\MonProjet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 234
```

Any thoughts on this issue? I've followed the steps and I'm getting this error. What is wrong there.. ?

Comment: If you are using Laravel >= 5.5 try not to include the provider in the `config/app.php` and do a `composer dump-autoload` from the cli in the project directory

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. please details,
and you can add your blade @ before render. example:-
@toastr()->render();

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I'm following exactly the steps on the tutorial in the link. Once I've installed the package and mention ```'providers' => [
    ...
    Yoeunes\Toastr\ToastrServiceProvider::class
    ...
];``` in my config/app.php I get the error above and I just can't work on my app anymore. I mean none of the routes works anymore. When I get that line commented it all works again fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I do not really understand your proposition.. Where should I put this ```@toastr()->render();```..?

Comment: You can use laravel-notify  is work same in toastr alert.its  so easy. https://github.com/Helmesvs/laravel-notify